# Prove divergence/convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n[\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}] $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Prove divergence/convergence of
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left[\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}\right] $$
my intuition tells me to think about telescopic sum because of the $(-1)^n$
but I don't know how to write a formal proof for this,
also
I checked wolfram alpha and it tells me divergence but the bad explanation

[wolframalpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqeEZ.png)
[wolframalpha2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfHAc.png)

but I know that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$ converges so i assume the same happens here aint i am right ?

can I get some help just to start the proof?

what I tried

> by the sentence that if a series converges then the sequence limit is
> $0$,   let's assume by contradiction that $(-1)^n\left[\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}\right] \rightarrow 0$ so
> $$\forall\varepsilon>0 ,\exists N\in \mathbb N,\forall n\in \mathbb
> > N,n>N,|a_n-L|<\varepsilon$$

> $$|a_n-L|<|(-1)^n\left[\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}\right]-0|=|(-1)^n[\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}]|=|(-1)^n|\cdot|[\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}]|=1\cdot\left[\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}\right]>\varepsilon\Rightarrow 
>  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (-1)^n\left[\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}\right]$$  does not exists

therefore the series  diverges

Comment: What do you think - the common term tends to zero?

Comment: What is the meaning of the bracket $[\cdot]$?

Comment: $[\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}] does not tend to zero $ but how do i base my asumpsion in an $\varepsilon \delta $ way ?

Comment: the [ ] is to say an integer value

Comment: Try to show, that after some $N$ the term $\left[\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}\right]$ remains more then $1$.

Comment: Then the common term does not converge to $0.$ Also the common term of the form  $(-1)^n\{(n/2)-[n/2]\}$ does not converge to $0.$

Comment: what is a common term?

Comment: For the square brackets to look correct, you have to use "\left" and "\right". I have done the first one for you, but I'm not doing the rest, so feel free to do them yourself as it looks a lot clearer.

Comment: For $\sum a_n$ the quantity $a_n$ is called the common term

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc The numbers $a_n$ of the  summation $\sum_n a_n$ are called the summands (or addends).

Comment: @MarkViola Sometimes it is called the general term. I repeated the notion "common" after the first comment by zkutch

Comment: Yes, it is also called the general term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$b_n=(-1)^n\left[\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}\right]\ $ does not converge to $0.$ Therefore, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ does not converge.